# How to duplicate formatting of dictionary extract, with italics?

Tags: support, formatting, quotes

When I quote from an online dictionary I like to duplicate the formatting as much as possible.

When using standard `>` block quoting I can't find a way to have a new line without inserting a blank line.  Adjacent lines are run together.

But if I use a `>` prefix followed by several blanks the lines are formatted as I enter them, without running adjacent lines together.

However, when I do this the standard `*` and `**` delimiters for italics and bold don't work.

Is there any way to get around this?

Example:

> ```
> This is one line
> This is the next line
> This line contains *italics* and **bold**
> ```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Could you provide a literal example? Do you just want a `<br>` to break the current line without starting a new paragraph?

Comment: @tchrist - Maybe <br> would do it.  I always forget that bit of HTML when formatting on SE.

Comment: 1) Yes, this would be a good thing to know how to do. 2) Not that the difficulty of formatting should be a bias, but quotes from dictionaries should only be supportive information, and not the primary content of answers. (This is more of a general admonition to others; there's been a lot of SWRs lately where the answerers give as their entire answer a word and its definition copied from a single dictionary. (which is a poor kind of answer))

Comment: @Mitch - In my most recent situation, someone was asking if any "authorities" gave a particular definition.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, that is a very good instance to quote. I wasn't pointing at you, I was just using example as a reminder to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Editing Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks), you can use two spaces after each line:

```
> This is one line  
> This is the next line  
> This line contains *italics* and **bold**
```

produces

> This is one line
>   This is the next line
>   This line contains *italics* and **bold**

Alternatively, you can put an HTML line break (`<br/>`) after each line, but that's more work to type.